# In Python, How to assign value of variable to the dictionary, where the variable will keep getting values for each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Ex:

```
for x in myresult:
    y=str(x)
    if y.startswith('(') and y.endswith(')'):
            y = y[2:-3]
            y=y.replace("\\","").replace(";",'')
            chr_num = y.find("property_name")
            chr_num=chr_num+15
            PropertyName = y[chr_num:-1]
            chr_num1 = y.find("phrase_value")
            chr_num1 = chr_num1 + 14
            chr_num2 = y.find("where")
            chr_num2=chr_num2-2
            PhraseValue = y[chr_num1:chr_num2]
```

This is the existing code. Now i want to store 'PhraseValue' in dictionary or array.

NOTE: PhraseValue will keep getting values for each iteraction

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question. In your case, obviously, `PropertyName` and `PhraseValue` are overwritten on each iteration and contains only the last values at the end of the loop.

If you want to store multiple values, the easiest structure is a list.

```
ret = [] # empty list
for x in some_iterator():
    y = some_computation(x)
    ret.append(y) # add the value to the list

# ret contains all the y's
```

If you want to use a dict, you have to compute a key and a value:

```
ret = {} # empty dict
for x in some_iterator():
    y = some_computation(x)
    k = the_key(x) # maybe k = x
    ret[k] = y # map k to y

# ret contains all the k's and their mapped values.
```

The choice between a list and a dict depends on your specific problem: use a dict if you want to find values by key, like in a dictionary; use a list if you need ordered values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `PropertyName` is the key, then you could simply add

```
results = {}
```

before the loop, and

```
results[PropertyName] = PhraseValue
```

as the last line of the `if` statement inside the loop.

This solution does have one problem. What if a given `PropertyName` occurs more than once? The above solution would only keep the last found value.
If you want to keep all values, you can use `collections.defaultdict`;

```
import collections

results = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Then as the last line of the if statement inside the loop;

```
results[PropertyName].append(PhraseValue)
```